# Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I am doing some basic form validation by adding a 'Please select...' option to a delivery method select box (cmbD_method), then making sure the user has selected a delivery method.  I am not able to modify the source, so my code adds the validation onto an existing function called validateUserDataFields().

However, no matter what option is selected, the alert message appears and the console shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

What am I missing?  My code is below:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> 

var delMeth = new Option('Please Select A Delivery Method', '0');

$(delMeth).html("Please Select A Delivery Method");
$("#cmbD_Method").append(delMeth);
$('#cmbD_Method').val(0);
$('#cmbD_Method').width($('#cmbD_Method').width() + 40);

var validate = validateUserDataFields;

validateUserDataFields = function () {
if ($('#cmbD_Method').val(0)) {
  alert('Please Select A Delivery Method');
  }
else {
  validate(); // call the original function
  }
};

</script>
```

Comment: if ($('#cmbD_Method').val() == '0')

Comment: Can you include any pertinent markup?

Comment: Can you isolate *which line* is throwing the exception? It is most odd ..

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: Hmmm- it is actually throwing from the page that includes the original function.  I will need to figure a better way to isolate, as the issue does not occur when I exclude this new function.

Answer (score 0):

@Rongsir answered the main part of the question- I needed

```
 if ($('#cmbD_Method').val() == '0')
```